# JS alert called from yes button from a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I already asked this question yesterday but I think I didn't explain my problem good. So I was trying to delete a table row if the return button is clicked but I also want to make sure that the click wasn't an accident so there should be a modal popup which asks again and if you click yes then the modal should close and the row should get removed. My problem is that the second click function which should get triggered in the modal if you click yes is not getting triggered.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var rowToDelete;

  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
  });

  $('#booked').click(function() {

    $('.ret').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      alert(id); //to test if this function gets triggered
      $('#myModal .delBtn').data('row-id', id); //set data id
      rowToDelete = $(this).closest('tr'); //store row in variable
    })
  });

  $('#booked').addClass('active'); //not necessary
  $('#book').removeClass('active');
  $('#admin').removeClass('active');

});

$(document).on("click", '#myModal .delBtn', function() {

  var rowId = $(this).data('row-id');
  alert("you removed" + rowId); //this alert never appears so this function is not getting triggered

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div id="booked">
    <div class="row scrollableBooked">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class='table table-bordered' id='bookedtable'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan='6' class='bookedHeader'>Booking for: example booking</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Serial Number</th>
              <th>Info</th>
              <th>Return</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 12)</td>
              <td><button value='11' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 25)</td>
              <td><button value='25' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 64)</td>
              <td><button value='64' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 34)</td>
              <td><button value='34' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Delete Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Return Device</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <p><b> Are you sure you want to return this device? </b></p>
                  This is a test.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delBtn">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: JS-fiddle:     https://jsfiddle.net/u7ofjprw/43/

Comment: your modal id is `deleteModal` and you are setting the `.delBtn` click handler to `#myModal .delBtn` set the proper id and it will work plus add `data-dismiss="modal"` on the `YES` button's HTML to close the modal and please try to paste your code in here instead of a link to somewhere else so people can help you.

Comment: could you edit my fiddle and send it back? I already tried this but maybe I did it wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **There were two issues with your code:**

1. The modal that you were calling was `myModal` whereas it should be `deleteModal`.
2. You were binding the `click` function on the class `ret` inside the `click` of the `#booked` div.

Below is the changed code snippet of your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var rowToDelete;

  $('#deleteModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
  });

  $('.ret').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    alert(id); //to test if this function gets triggered
    $('#deleteModal .delBtn').data('row-id', id); //set data id
    rowToDelete = $(this).closest('tr'); //store row in variable
  });

  $('#booked').addClass('active'); //not necessary
  $('#book').removeClass('active');
  $('#admin').removeClass('active');

});

$(document).on("click", '#deleteModal .delBtn', function() {

  var rowId = $(this).data('row-id');
  alert("you removed" + rowId); //this alert never appears so this function is not getting triggered

});
```

```html
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div id="booked">
    <div class="row scrollableBooked">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class='table table-bordered' id='bookedtable'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan='6' class='bookedHeader'>Booking for: example booking</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Serial Number</th>
              <th>Info</th>
              <th>Return</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 12)</td>
              <td><button value='11' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 25)</td>
              <td><button value='25' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 64)</td>
              <td><button value='64' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Device 1</td>
              <td>12345 </td>
              <td>lorem ipsum (id 34)</td>
              <td><button value='34' class='btn ret' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal'>return</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Delete Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Return Device</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <p><b> Are you sure you want to return this device? </b></p>
                  This is a test.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright. You issue is `#myModal`. The modal you are trying to select is `#deleteModal`. There are 2 places that you use `#myModal`. Change them to `#deleteModal` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The click event is not firing because the element id 'myModal' does not exist. If you replace myModal with deleteModal, the alert will pop up.

```
$(document).on("click", '#deleteModal .delBtn', function () {...
```